# Prove that $A_7$ has no subgroup of order $504$

Tags: group-theory

Why can't $A_7$ have a subgroup of order $504$?  I'd like to show any such subgroup would have to be normal in $A_7$, but it would have index $5$, and I see no obvious way to show this.

Comment: Suppose $G$ were such a subgroup. Let $A_7$ act on the set of cosets of $G$ by left multiplication.

Comment: Okay, here's what I got.  If $G$ is such a subgroup, and $S$ is the set of left cosets of $G$ in $A_7$, then there is an induced homomorphism $$A_7 \xrightarrow{\Phi} Sym(S)$$ given by the formula $\Phi(\psi)(\phi G) = \psi \circ \phi S$.  Since the kernel of this homomorphism is a normal subgroup of $A_7$ which is contained in $H$, it is automatically trivial which makes $A_7$ isomorphic to a subgroup of $Sym(S) \cong S_5$.  Hence $7!/2$ divides $5!$, which is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is already given in the comments. Since the questions stayed here for more than $2$ years unanswered, I will put an answer here. Suppose that there was such a subgroup $H$. Then we had a monomorphism $H\hookrightarrow A_7$ with $ [A_7:H] = 5$. By letting $A_7$ act on the coset space $A_7/H$ gives a homomorphism $A_7\rightarrow S_5$.
Since $A_7$ is simple, the kernel of this homomorphism must be trivial or all of $A_7$. Letting $x$ be in $A_7 \setminus H$, we see $x.H = xH ≠ H$, so the action is not trivial (thus the kernel is not all of $A_7$), and $|A_7| = 2520$ does not divide $120 = |S_5|$, so the kernel is not trivial. This is a contradiction.

Comment: A slightly different argument: it is easy to verify that the kernel of the homomorphism $A_7 \to S_5$ is $\bigcap_{g \in G}gHg^{-1}$ (the **core** of $H$), which is a subgroup of $H$, hence the kernel cannot be all of $A_7$, so it must be trivial. Therefore $A_7$ injects into $S_5$, but this is impossible as $|A_7| > |S_5$.